# A mutable of set length with cyclic append and slicing

Tags: python, numpy, deque

I have a list `data_list` that is supposed to stay a certain length `x` all the time.
I get new information every certain time interval and then do the following

```
new_info  # type: list
data_list.extend(new_info)
del data_list[:len(new_info)]
```

however this *very* slow (I think the del part copies the entire list).

In addition after each cyclic insertion I slice the list and perform all kinds of numeric calculations using numpy.
This means that each time, I am creating a new numpy array for the calculations.

what would you recommend? 
It doesn't matter if a recommended data structure it's not in the standard library.

Note:
I don't have all the `new_info`'s in the beginning, so this can't be done in a batch manner.

---

my attempt

```
import sys
import itertools
from typing import Iterable
from collections import deque

class SetLengthDeque(deque):
    def __getitem__(self, s):
        # for me the common case is a slice so i prefer this, 
        # rather then check the type of s each time
        try:
            start, stop, step = s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxsize, s.step or 1
            return list(itertools.islice(self, start, stop, step))
        except AttributeError:  # not a slice but an int
            return self[s]
```

however `deque` is actually a linked list, and a cyclic array. 
It is around 2 orders of magnitude faster in the insertion, however when slicing it is 7 times slower then a list.
plus i still have to create a numpy array each iteration.

Comment: use a numpy array and create a new one off of a sliced view of previous array and your missing/new element.

Comment: wouldnt this be as slow of an iteration as the list one ? i essentially will be copying  the `data_list` each iteration

Comment: Use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) maybe? You can set a max length when you create it.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh no, using an array will not make anything quicker. In fact, you're more likely to get horrible efficiency from copying. There's nothing about a 1D array slice vs a list that makes this viable

Comment: numpy slicing is fancy. i think you'll see gains as long as you do not iterate through it. @moshevi The idea also is that you are not dealing with deletion as a slice.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh What does "fancy" mean? If you're referring to "fancy indexing" then you're even further off the mark because that _mandates_ a full copy.

Comment: I honestly do not know then. apologies if im off the mark. @roganjosh

Comment: @ParitoshSingh it's not something to apologise for; this is the only way to learn :) But I really cannot see anything but drawbacks to numpy here. I'm pretty sure a `deque` is the way to go, which I linked to

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts:

1. If the starting point is a subclass of *deque()*, the your code `list(itertools.islice(self, start, stop, step))` is likely the fastest way to do slicing.  The only improvement I can see would be to add special case that with `reversed(self)` when the leftmost slice index is to the right of the center-line.
2. To support the fixed-length requirement, use deque's *maxlen* argument.
3. The worrisome part is the requirement, "that each time, I am creating a new numpy array for the calculations".  That is the expensive part.  The general rule is that if numpy is required, the data should be in numpy start to finish.  I would just let the numpy array grow to the maximum tolerable size and let numpy's fast, flexible slicing provide necessary views of the data without copying and without conversion to and from Python objects.

Answer (score -1):

I think `data_list = data_list[len(new_info):]` is good. Slices are accessed O(n).

Here's the thing though, I think neither strictly conform to your requirement, because in between lines 2 and 3 there is a (admittedly tiny) interval where the list `len` is `len(data_list) + len(new_info)`.

```
data_list.extend(new_info) # Arbitrarily long
data_list[len(new_info):]
```

What if we do it all at once?

```
data_list = data_list.extend(new_info)[len(new_info):]
```

`extend` has no return value so we get an error.

Edit: this seems to handle it, but I haven't tested it thoroughly

```
if len(new_info) < len(data_list):
  data_list.extend(new_info)
  data_list[len(new_info):]
else:
  data_list = new_info[0-len(data_list):]
data_list
```

Edit again: I also tried it with `deque` per joshrogan

```
d = deque(data_list, maxlen=len(data_list))
j = deque([x for x in range(30)])
d.extend(j)
```

I think one of these is probably more performant than the other in your use case and would be interested to hear about it!

Comment: "Slices are accessed O(1)" - no they're not. Slicing requires copying the sliced portion of the list.

Comment: That's not how I meant it but you're right that O(n) is clearer I will edit @user2357112